# Will this structure emit EM waves when excited by out-of-plane time varying magnetic field?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic, magnetic-flux

Say I create a structure from copper that looks like the figure shown below. It's an open circle whose ends terminate in protruding wires of length x. If I excite this with an out-of plane time varying magnetic field B (say B0*cosft), will the protruding wires emit EM waves? If yes, will the emitted radiation have a frequency of f? And will x affect the power of the emitted radiation? Any brief explanation will be helpful.[image: structure].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will the protruding wires emit EM waves?

Yes. But then, there will be EM waves all over such a setup anyway.

> If yes, will the emitted radiation have a frequency of f?

Yes, of course. This is a linear, time-invariant (LTI) system, so it couldn't have any other frequency.

> And will x affect the power of the emitted radiation?

Yes. Look up [dipole antenna](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dipole_antenna). The radiation varies in a complex way, depending on how x relates to the frequency (wavelength) and how the inductance and capacitance of the coil resonate with the antenna.

Answer (score 0):

Biot-Savart solved this a long time ago. In short the only the magnetic field inside the coil will drive a current. This is reversible, a current will also drive a magnetic field. This is due to the way the fields integrate around the coil. See [this](http://dev.physicslab.org/document.aspx?doctype=3&filename=magnetism_biotsavartlaw2.xml). The field already in place opposes changes to it [slides](http://slideplayer.com/slide/1627886/)